# Is there a way to incorporate a Dynamic Named Range with a column that has multiple VLOOKUPS from various sources?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically I wanted to pull several reports together using a master column. That way, when record is pulled, all of the corresponding data comes in relating to that specific number. However, I wanted to include a sense of automatic updating with the data so that when new records are updated in the other reports, the master column accounts for this and updates accordingly.

I am using VLOOKUPS For this code, so as to allow future updates from other people to be relatively simple and easy to read. I VLOOKUP the master column from a unique ID from various sources, and the data I need comes from other sources that are related to it based on the Unique ID. I was reading up about using the Dynamic Named Range, and I have a code, but it doesn't work for some reason. I wanted it to be able to take in updates from various sources for the master column, and have the data update from various sources accordingly.

Here's the excel formula I was looking at as an example:

```
 =Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$C:$C))
```

The results should look like this:

Master Column    Section       Data

1.34555           2           This is data.

2.45588           2           So is this.

3.77743           3           Something here.

4.92222           1           Let's go fishing

5.33713           2           Don't spoil Avengers Endgame

Those pull fine, but when a new line is added in a report:

6. 22221          3           Sweet party.

It won't account for the new data. I wanted to have it so when a user refreshes data, any new data is accounted for.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `COUNTIF` needs a range and a criteria, you are missing the latter. Perhaps you need `COUNTA` instead. In any case might be easier to use a Table.

Comment: I see. Thank you!